# Fail to send comma with keyboard.sendkeys

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have tried to send the following command to type comma:

```
Keyboard.Sendkeys(",");
```

Instead of typing `','` I got `'''`.

Any ideas?

I also tried `Keyboard.Sendkeys("{,}");`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
Keyboard.SendKeys(",").
```

Please try to use below way

```
ControlId.Text = ","
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I found the reason.

It's related to windows keyboard definition.
When another keyboard is define in the regional language and even if the default keybard is english, the keyboard.sendkeys will send wrong characters.

For sure microsoft bug.

Answer (score -1):

The issue could be because of your Keyboard language setting.